# How to validate for Values "0" or "00" or "000" for textfield which has the regex and some accepted values

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

```
var myregex = /^[0-9][0-9]{0,3}$|^[0-9][0-9]{0,3}[\.][0-9]$/;
if(!myregex.test($('#txt1').val()) || $('#txt1').val()=="0"){
    alert("Please Enter Correct value");
}
```

Now My mandatory things are it should

1. follow Regex
2. we should not able to enter the value "0" or "00" or "000"

So my above if() raises an alert if the user enter a  "0" and if we enter "00" or "000" or "0000" it doesnot catch it .But if we enter "00000" it catches it due to regex. How can i handle for 2,3,4 zeros .Now Here I can put a regex which doesnot accept zeros such as this one "`/^[^0].*$/`" but My textfield should Accepts this values as right (0.2,0.3,0.4) .so i cannot use this regex.

Comment: Can you provide more examples of accepted inputs and not accepted inputs? That would help us answer your question more accurately.

Comment: What about `01`, `001`, `0001`, `0.0` and `1.0`?  Are any of those acceptable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avoid regex, it's a nightmare to get exactly right, and to maintain in the future. Instead, use built-in JS string parsing functionality:

```
var val = parseFloat($('#txt1').val());
if (isNaN(val) || (val === 0))
{
    alert("Please Enter Correct value");
}
```

Comment: @ken:What If you enter 2 Zeros.

Comment: @ken:Would the Above Regex be satisfied with the ParseFloat() Function.

Comment: Did you test it? Remove all of your code and put mine in its place. 2 zeros should be treated like 1 zero which should be treated like 1000 zeros. And I don't understand your second question. However, let me restate: I would encourage you NOT to use regex for this; use what I've provided.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's regular. But it's also ugly to match. Using a dedicated float parser is the right thing to do.

Comment: Not even gonna waste time with a regex version, I can tell already it'd take 10x longer than what I've already done.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[1-9]\d{0,3}(?:\.\d)?$|^0\.[1-9]$/
```

The first alternative matches any number from `1.0` to `9999.9`.  The first digit has to be at least `1`, which eliminates leading zeroes.  The fraction part is optional (`(?:\.\d)?`), so it also matches integers from `1` to `9999`.  The second alternative handles the special cases of `0.1` through `0.9`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your regular expression requires 0 through 9999, or 0.0 through 9999.9, but you do not want to accept a 0 alone, or a series of zeros.

If that's the case, I'd say use something similar to [ken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587967/how-to-validate-for-values-0-or-00-or-000-for-textfield-which-has-the-regex/4588024#4588024) and process it as a float, then check that the float is above 0 and below 9999.9:

```
var val = parseFloat($("#txt1").val());
if(isNan(val) || val <= 0 || val > 9999.9) {
    alert("Please enter a value between 0 and 9999.9");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use your regex and just add a check that the string doesn't consist entirely of zeroes, you can add a negative lookahead expression: `(?!0+$)` and enclose the alternation in a non-capturing group:

```
/^(?!0+$)(?:[0-9][0-9]{0,3}|[0-9][0-9]{0,3}[\.][0-9])$/
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for Regex or any of that, quite simple.

```
if(('#txt1').val() < 0.1 ){
    alert("Please Enter Correct value");
}
```

There you go, problem solved